# differential equation: $ y''-2y'+y=x\sin x$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Someone can help me to solve this differential equation with method of undetermined coefficient.
$$ y''-2y'+y=x\sin x$$
Thanks

Comment: I have done a stupid mistake, thank you anyway

Answer (score 2):

So first you need to get the solution to the homogeneous ODE, and the characteristic equation is $$r^2-2r+1=0=(r-1)^2,$$ so you have two repeated real roots, you know what to do with that from there. Now onto the particular solution. Since we have a $\sin x$ multiplied by a polynomial, we have $$y_p = (Ax+B)\sin x + (Cx+D)\cos x$$

Now from here you have all of the materials needed to solve the problem. Take the derivative of the particular solution twice, sub in, and equate coefficients.

Comment: Thanks I have done a stupid mistake...

Comment: The particular solution is wrong: it should be $(Ax+B)\sin x+(Cx+D)\cos x$.

Comment: That is the same thing enzotib, expand my solution out and you'll see, those are just arbitrary constants.

Comment: @Panphobia: no, it is not the same, because in your scheme the ratio of coefficients of $\cos x$ and $\sin x$ is always $D/C$, while in my scheme depends on $x$. Also you can eliminate a constant in your scheme, given that only the four products $AC,AD,BC,BD$ have meaning. Finally, if you try to determine the solution with your scheme it fails.

Comment: How can I find the particular solution ”the usual way”? That is, $\frac{1}{D^2-2D+1} (xsinx)$? I saw a variant of byparts being employed, but couldn’t make sense.

Answer (score 0):

As the DE is linear we have

$$
y = y_h + y_p
$$

with

$$
\cases{
y''_h-2y'_h+y_h = 0\\
y''_p-2y'_p+y_p = x\sin x
}
$$

The homogeneous has the solution

$$
y_h(x) = c_1 e^x+c_2 x e^x
$$

now for the particular we propose a solution (variation of constants method) such that

$$
y_p = c_1(x) e^x+c_2(x)x e^x
$$

from $y''_p-2y'_p+y_p = x \sin x$ we obtain

$$
e^x \left(c_1''(x)+x c_2''(x)+2 c_2'(x)\right)-x \sin (x) = 0
$$

now as $c_1(x), c_2(x)$ are independent we equate

$$
\cases{
c''_1(x)e^x = x \sin x\\
xc''_2(x)+2c'_2(x) = 0}
$$

Here as $y_p$ is a particular solution we can specify the integration constants at our profit. Now solving for $c_1(x), c_2(x)$ we have finally

$$
y = y_h + y_p
$$